# Remove Currency reference in visual force field

Tags: visualforce

This is my custom visual force section:
[image]

I would like to remove currency reference like "EUR" from values in columns.

These are tags in my Visual Foce page:

```
 <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Olis}" var="oli" rows="8" rendered="{!numOfOlis>0}">            
        <apex:column headerValue="Action" styleClass="actionColumn">
          <apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.OpportunityLineItem.Edit, oli.Id)}">Edit</apex:outputLink>
          &nbsp;|&nbsp;
          <apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.OpportunityLineItem.Delete, oli.Id)}">Del</apex:outputLink>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column headerValue="Service">
          <apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.OpportunityLineItem.View, oli.Id)}">{!oli.PricebookEntry.Name}</apex:outputLink>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column headerValue="Sales Price" value="{!oli.UnitPrice}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!oli.ListPrice}"/>    
        <apex:column value="{!oli.CurrencyIsoCode}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!oli.Unit_of_Measure__c}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!oli.Description}"/>
        <apex:column headerValue="Deal Row">
        </apex:column>

      </apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Thanks in advantage for any advice.

Thanks to Birthus we have a solution,it´s important to format output text field:

```
    <apex:column headerValue="Sales Price">
      <apex:outputText value="{0, number,###,###,##0.00}">
        <apex:param value="{!oli.ListPrice}" />
      </apex:outputText>
    </apex:column>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about display this field as OutputText?

```
<apex:OutputText value = "{!oli.ListPrice}" \>
```